# From Direct3d to OpenGL

Tags: opengl, direct3d

I currently rewrite an old Visual Basic application in java, a large part of the work involves replacing Direct3d with jogl.
 Since I have **no** experience in dealing with Direct3d and only minimal experience using Opengl, I am stuck on finding appropriate replacements for the api calls.

Are there any good guides/tutorials or references?

**Edit:**
Additional information:

- Direct3D version 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could try and browse through the code of this D3D -> OpenGL wrapper library:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dxglwrap (using it as a reference I mean)

You can browse through it here: http://dxglwrap.cvs.sourceforge.net/dxglwrap/

Comment: dxglwrap is missing quite a few function implementations most currently do nothing, and others ignore a large number of parameter values

Answer (score 4):

I'd also recommend going through the [OpenGL Red Book](http://glprogramming.com/red/) and investing some time in typing in some samples and playing with them. OpenGL Red Book deals with using GL in C, so I recommend you go through it in C or C++ before going to JOGL.

You don't have to play with everything, but making a few examples work in C++ would be great before you go on.

Otherwise, if you don't have the time or interest or will to study GL, just follow [NeHe tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) as mentioned in other answer, but take a peek every now and then into the Red Book for additional explanations.

Comment: This is a great suggestion. Diving into OpenGL and/or DirectX with no idea of how it's normally used in the flow of the program will probably just drive you nuts. Going through a few simple examples like just rendering a simple triangle, then ideally rendering a few simple objects in a rendering loop, will help you a lot in understanding the flow of an OpenGL program.

Comment: Not only that, but getting into the mind of designers of preferred API is an extremely good idea, and there's no better resource for that than Red Book!

Answer (score 3):

The NeHe tutorials are a pretty good intro. They [start here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/lesson.asp?index=01). Having Direct3D experience, you'll probably buzz through some of them pretty quickly.

Comment: Josefx said that he doesn't have any Direct3D experience.

Answer (score 1):

NeHe tutorials will get you up to speed quickly. If you have time and need for something more comprehensive, you should get the [OpenGL SuperBible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321498828).